# Is Google Chrome for Android Beta compatible with the 4.0.3 emulator in the Android SDK?

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-emulator

Is Google Chrome for Android Beta compatible with the Android SDK (Android 4.0.3 system image)?

I tried installing the Chrome .apk file and it installed fine. When running the application I can see the introductory screens, but when I try to navigate to a webpage, all I see is a blank screen. The page appears to be loading indefinitely.

I also tried the stock Android browser and it works fine, so that rules out a network connectivity issue.

The image appears to be stripped of a bunch of packages - Google Login Service/Market, etc. Could that be the cause of Chrome for Android not working correctly or am I not doing something the right way?

Comment: I don't think the emulator image implements hardware acceleration, which i think Chrome requires. Mostly an educated guess, but that seems like a likely culprit (meaning it just isn't going to work at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No im sorry, but Chrome for Android needs hardware acceleration, so until Google change that (i dont think thats gonna happen sorry) you can't do that. But maybe in the future.

Sorry, i know it wasn't the answer you really wants to hear...